# Generating one time series from merged irregular time series

Tags: r, merge, time-series

I am an R novice currently working on a project related to monthly stock prices for various firms from 1960 to now. I have multiple excel spreadsheets, each with multiple time series for multiple firms. I am able to merge, and I end with a dataset of p=4 and n=610,000. What I am looking for however, is one single time series with tickers as variables. ie p=1600 and n=730 (approximately).

```
have<-data.frame(list(Time=c(1,2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2,3, 4), Firm=c('A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'), Price=c(15, 5, 10, 5, 25, 20, 15, 'NA', 'NA', 35, 85, 50)))



want<-data.frame(list(Time=c(1,2,3,4), A=c(15,5,10,5), B=c(25,20,15,'NA'), C=c('NA', 35, 85, 50)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
have %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Firm, values_from = Price)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Time A     B     C    
#  <dbl> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1     1 15    25    NA   
#2     2 5     20    35   
#3     3 10    15    85   
#4     4 5     NA    50
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. My apologies for responding late, I did not expect an answer so quickly. Thank you again!